# $k\in \mathbb Z,\ (k,p)=1$ the element $k\cdot1_A$ is invertible

Tags: ring-theory, characteristics

Let $A$ be a ring. The order of $1_A$ in (A,+) is p (prime). For $k\in \mathbb Z,\  (k,p)=1$ the element $k\cdot1_A$ is invertible. I tried to prove this.

$(k,p)=1 \to \exists m,n\in \mathbb Z\  s.t \ \ mk+np=1$. I don't know what can I do now.

Comment: What is $(k\cdot 1_A)(m\cdot 1_A)?$

Comment: It is $km$  ....

Comment: It's $km\cdot 1_A$, and use $mk=1-np$

Comment: But the + and . are not the same from "$mk+np=1$"(these are the standard + and . from Z)

Comment: That's why I'm confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track.

Since $(k\cdot1_A)(m\cdot1_A)=km\cdot1_A=(1-np)\cdot1_A=1\cdot1_A-np\cdot1_A=1_A-n0_A=1_A,$

$(k\cdot1_A)$ has an inverse in $A$, namely, $m\cdot1_A.$

Comment: Thank you very much!